# Can "ケンカになったのよ" be talking about a hypothetical?

Tags: interpretation

In the latest chapter of One Piece this exchange happens between おでん, a skilled swordsman wondering why his disciples won't learn his style and his wife, トキ:

> おでん: "おでん二刀流"最強だぞ?なぜ受けつがない!!

> トキ: ふふふケンカになったのよ。誰が一番弟子になるかで真剣の大ゲンカ。あなたが好きすぎて死者が出るとこだった

In the English version this was translated as:

> Oden: But Oden Two Sword Style is the greatest there is! Why won't they learn it?

> Toki: Because they would've fought. A great big fight over who would be your foremost disciple. They love you so much that they would've killed each other.

My confusion comes from the fact that the English translation states that a fight "would've" happened, not that it did happen.

"あなたが好きすぎて死者が出るとこだった" specially seems like something that would imply they did indeed come close to dying after fighting over who'd be the number one disciple.

Based on this context, is it possible that "ケンカになったのよ" is referring to a hypothetical situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. From what I can see from the given context, 死者が出る is something that could have happened in the past, but ケンカ is something that did happen in the past. This is probably a mistake made by the translator. The correct translation is simply:

> Toki: Because **they fought**.